# Obtaining all groups of n pairs of numbers that pass condition

Tags: algorithm

I have a list with certain combinations between two numbers:

```
[1 2] [1 4] [1 6] [3 4] [5 6] [3 6] [2 3] [4 5] [2 5]
```

Now I want to make groups of 3 combinations, where each group contains all six digits once, e.g.:

```
[1 2] [3 6] [4 5] is valid
[1 4] [2 3] [5 6] is valid
[1 2] [2 3] [5 6] is invalid
```

Order is not important.
How can I arrive upon a list of all possible groups, without employing a brute forcing algorithm?

The language it is implemented in doesn't matter. Description of an algorithm that could achieve this is enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: `How can I arrive upon a list of all possible groups, without employing a brute forcing algorithm?` Your solution is going ot be O(n^3) worst case regardless of algorithm, since this is the worst case size of output...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan it involves finding different ways to book multiple fares between the same two locations

Comment: @amit O(n^3) would be acceptable since n is expected to stay relatively small

Comment: Are duplicate pairs allowed?

Comment: Does the first pair always start with 1?

Comment: @BrentWashburne no thats just a coincidence in the example

Comment: @edwardmp The brute force is O(n^3), check all possible triplets.

Comment: Using Dynamic Programming can improve this a little bit. But when n is very big, Dynamic Programming still gives `O(n^3/4)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that there are only finitely many possible pairs of elements you can pick from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Specifically, there are (6P2) = 30 of them if you consider order relevant and (6 choose 2) = 15 if you don't. Even the simple "try all triples" algorithm that runs in cubic time in this case will only have to look at at most (30 choose 3) = 4,060 triples, which is a pretty small number. I doubt that you'd have any problems in practice just doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function in Python that picks a pair of numbers from a list, and then calls itself with the remaining list:

```
def pairs(l, picked, ok_pairs):
    n = len(l)
    for a in range(n-1):
        for b in range(a+1,n):
            pair = (l[a],l[b])
            if pair not in ok_pairs:
                continue
            if picked and picked[-1][0] > pair[0]:
                continue
            p = picked+[pair]
            if len(l) > 2:
                pairs([m for i,m in enumerate(l) if i not in [a, b]], p, ok_pairs)
            else:
                print p

ok_pairs = set([(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (3, 4), (5, 6), (3, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5)])
pairs([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], ok_pairs)
```

The output (of 6 triplets) is:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 5)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Nice approach but [3, 5], [4, 6] is not in the input list so  can't be in the output list

Comment: Added another parameter `ok_list` to filter the pairs

Comment: Also, order is not important thus the same combination of 3 pairs but in another order should not count as another pair

Comment: The list is now filtered for unique pairs by enforcing an increasing value in the pairs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using Python set arithmetic:

```
pairs = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (3, 4), (5, 6), (3, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5)]
n = len(pairs)
for i in range(n-2):
    set1 = set(pairs[i])
    for j in range(i+1,n-1):
        set2 = set(pairs[j])
        if set1 & set2:
            continue
        for k in range(j+1,n):
            set3 = set(pairs[k])
            if set1 & set3 or set2 & set3:
                continue
            print pairs[i], pairs[j], pairs[k]
```

The output is:

```
(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6)
(1, 2) (3, 6) (4, 5)
(1, 4) (5, 6) (2, 3)
(1, 4) (3, 6) (2, 5)
(1, 6) (3, 4) (2, 5)
(1, 6) (2, 3) (4, 5)
```